# On Eclipse, is there a way to modify several include paths in one shot?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, path, include

I'm trying to change the include paths from relative path to fixed path.  Is there a way to do it in a bulk?  Or do I need to manually edit one by one?

I'm currently going to 
C/C++ Build -> Settings -> ** Compiler -> Includes

And have to manually edit the path from something like:
../../../../../platform/hal/rtc
../../../../../platform/hal/sai
../../../../../platform/hal/sim

To 
"C:\Freescale\KSDK_1.0.0/platform/hal/rtc" 
"C:\Freescale\KSDK_1.0.0/platform/hal/sai" 
"C:\Freescale\KSDK_1.0.0\platform\hal\sim\"

I wonder if there's a way to export this to an XML file or something and then import it.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this issue before in a workspace that contains more than 40+ similar C++ projects. The way I deal with it is to write a shell script that modifies the `.cproject` files on disk:

1. Use `find` to recursively find the `.cproject` files that I need to modify.
2. Use `sed` to search and replace inside each file using `sed s/find-expression/replace-expression/g < .cproject > .cproject.tmp`.
3. When I'm happy that the `.cproject.tmp` files contain the correct replacements then I add `mv .cproject.tmp .cproject` to the script to finalise the operation.

Since you're using Windows you'll need to get your projects into an environment where shell-scripting is easy - cygwin or msys are both powerful enough to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Includes ... (then possibly your language), there is an export settings button which has a checkbox which includes the includes path. To import these settings into another project, you would use the import settings button when you open the properties to the same place in another project.

Comment: Thanks hiandbaii.  But when I export this it would still be in "../.." (ie relative path).